# changing a program to become a service?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, service, client-server

i want to create a application that can run as a service and also another program (in c++) that can communicate with it. Basically i want the program to send messages to the service and the service just echoes them back to the program

sample output of program would be something like this:
*Please input your message: hello
Receive response from server: hello*

i have a very simple client server program in UDP that does this - server echoes back the messages the clients sends. **so my question is can i change the server to become a service and change the client so it still communicates with the service? and if so how is this done?**

i have never used code to create a service before so if someone can link any tutorials that would be great

heres the program i want to change:
server

```
    void InitWinsock()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SOCKET socketS;

    InitWinsock();
    struct sockaddr_in local;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(1234);
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    socketS = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    bind(socketS,(sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local));
    while (1)
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("Waiting...\n");
        if (recvfrom(socketS,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen)!=SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Received message from %s: %s\n",inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr), buffer);
            sendto(socketS, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&from, fromlen);
        }
        Sleep(500);
    }
    closesocket(socketS);

    return 0;
}
```

client:

```
void InitWinsock()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SOCKET socketC;

    InitWinsock();
    struct sockaddr_in serverInfo;
    int len = sizeof(serverInfo);
    serverInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(1234);
    serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    socketC = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    while (1)
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("Please input your message: ");
        scanf("%s", buffer);
        if (strcmp(buffer,"exit") == 0)
            break;
        if (sendto(socketC, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&serverInfo, len) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            if (recvfrom(socketC, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&serverInfo, &len) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("Receive response from server: %s\n", buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    closesocket(socketC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [The Complete Service Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: thanks for the link. but can i just put that code into my existing program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [service example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as sergmat said.  Use the code in Svp.cpp, and put it into your server.  Update the `SVCNAME` to your service name.  Take the code in your `_tmain` and put it into the bottom of `SvcInit` where the `TO_DO: Perform work until service stops` is.  Take out the `while` loop below it.

As an aside, your server has a `Sleep(500)` in the main loop.  That's unnecessary as the server will block on the `recv` anyway.

To terminate the service, instead of using the `ghSvcStopEvent`, I'd just make the socket handle and some `closing` flag global, then set the flag and close the socket when you get the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` signal.

You'll have a few more cleanup details but that should more than get you started...

Answer (score 0):

Forget about changing your code, just use [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890/en-us).

Comment: Srvany does work for things you can't change. That doesn't mean you should use it for things you *can* change.

Comment: I would prefer using it to adding Windows-specific code into what is otherwise a perfectly portable application, but in this case the OP seems to be set on Windows anyway, true.